# HTML Imagemap with PHP and Javascript / User can select Colors

Tags: php, javascript, html

Ok, this is the current project http://pureblackgroup.com/test/

Is it possible to make it like my scribble here? http://pureblackgroup.com/test/example.jpg

I pay 100$ to 500$ for a solution!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this solve your problem? http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/examples/usa.html

It's the ImageMapster jQuery plugin. Have a look at the demo above. You can add rollovers and active states to an image using an image map. You can set these using CSS or an alternate image.

You could achieve what you're after by having two images. One where everything is 'off', and one where everything is 'on'. You then set this as the alternate image and you should be sorted. You can group image map areas so that you can highlight more than one at a time and set image map areas to be highlighted when the page loads.

It's fairly well documented and has come in really handy for my work a number of times.

Any other functions can be added using jQuery if you need them.

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?docs.html

Comment: It's a bit of a pain to set up but once you get there it's a really good plug in. No reward needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do with [HTML5 canvas](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-canvas-element). Mozilla has [an excellent tutorial about this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas).

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions come to mind:

- create a PNG or GIF file with each part separatly, in all possible colors (as you write you already did), with transparent background. Display then one over another, each as a different layer, to compose your picture. Then, above it place a fully transparent picture, and define your imagemap on it. Then you just need to create appopriate click handlers on image map - each click should change the source of appropriate image part to a picture in requested color.
- display your graphic as a `<canvas>`, and recolor it using javascript. You still need a transparent overlay with imagemap, as I don't think they are supported for `<canvas>` tag. This solution is available only if all the target browsers support HTML5 canvas.

No reward money needed, thanks :)

Comment: ok, its not compatible with ie7 or ie8

Comment: The GIF solution should work even on ie6. Transparent PNGs should be properly supported on ie7 and ie8.

Comment: maybe I can contact you socha23? stackoverflow chat or email?

Comment: @celebo sure: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5610/room-for-socha23-and-celebo